# How to plot and shade on Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: math-software, wolfram-alpha

Many Mathematica parameters don't work on Wolfram Alpha. I tried `filling -> f` which it does not recognize.

I am trying to plot a simple region bounded by $y = x^2$ and $y = x$ and shade that region in red.

I typed in

```
 plot[x^2,x,{x,0,1}] red filling
```

and I got something really dumb. I don't want to make those inequality plots either.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried enabling interactivity?

Comment: I used up my 14-day trial. Is there no way to go around it?

Comment: It manages to interpet `plot area between x and x^2` ([see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+area+between+x+and+x%5E2) for WA link, [see here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rPKtA.png) for image). Is the red shading absolutely necessary?

Comment: Hmmm I guess it's kinda okay. It's not REALLY that important...though it wouldn't hurt to know.

Comment: I mean the method fails for circles

Comment: [It interprets `plot area inside x^2+y^2 = 1` correctly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+area+inside+x%5E2%2By%5E2+%3D+1). I don't have a general approach to coming up with the right input, but it seems to parse English commands reasonably well.

Comment: It doesn't work if i add another circle like     [code] plot area inside x^2+y^2 = 1 and x^2 + y^2 = 4[/code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `region x^2<x`:

[image]

Arbitrary characters to exceed arbitrary limit.